# BwuDatagrid and PaperDropdownMenu like a field editor

Tags: dart, polymer, paper-elements

I try add custom editor for BwuDatagrid in newInstance I tried to write:

```
PaperDropdownMenu dropMenu = new dom.Element.tag('paper-dropdown-menu');

PaperListbox listBox = new dom.Element.tag('paper-listbox');

makePapersElements(){
  List _items = new List();

  for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++){
    PaperItem item = new dom.Element.tag('paper-item');
    item.text = i;

    _items.add(item);
  }

  return  _items;
}

List<PaperItem> items  = makePapersElements();

listBox.children.addAll(items);

dropMenu.append(listBox);

args.container.append(dropMenu);
listBox.selected = 2;
```

But i have got wrong structure:

[image]

Then I try:

```
args.container.appendHtml(
    ''' <paper-material>
          <paper-dropdown-menu class='dropdown-menu'>
          <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
          </paper-listbox>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>
        </paper-material>''',
    treeSanitizer: new NullTreeSanitizer());

PaperDropdownMenu menu = dom.querySelector('paper-dropdown-menu');
PaperListbox listbox = menu.querySelector('paper-listbox');

listbox.nodes.addAll(makePapersElements());

listbox.selected = 8;
```

With treeSanitizer:

```
class NullTreeSanitizer implements dom.NodeTreeSanitizer {
  void sanitizeTree(node) {}
}
```

[image]

It's works, but position of selected element not in focus.
And scrollTop does not work too:

```
listbox.scrollTop = 120;
```

How I can focus selected element in paper-dropdown-menu?

Comment: I get answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689312/programmatically-create-polymer-elements-in-dart