# Programmatically create polymer Elements in Dart

Tags: dart, polymer

Need add polymer paper-dropdown-menu in DOM.
I try this code:

```
    makePapersElements() {
      List _items = new List();

      for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        PaperItem item = new dom.Element.tag('paper-item');
        item.text = i;

        _items.add(item);
      }

      return _items;
    }
```

And add nodes in PaperListbox then in PaperDropdownMenu:

```
    List<PaperItem> items = makePapersElements();

    var element = new dom.Element.tag('div');

    PaperDropdownMenu dropMenu = new PaperDropdownMenu();
    PaperListbox listBox = new dom.Element.tag('paper-listbox');


    dropMenu.append(listBox);
    listBox.nodes.addAll(items);

    element.nodes.add(dropMenu);

    $['example'].nodes.add(element);
```

It's not work currently:

[image]

How it can be done?

Update: Added Gist
https://gist.github.com/Rasarts/a0b6710e234ec8b4aa37f90e4cd14839

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `PaperDropDownMenu` and `Paperlistbox` with `new Xxx()`, no need for `new dom.Element.tag('Xxx')` because these elements contain a constructor for convenience where this is done already

- https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer_elements/blob/7912e0e6641155505007a89140f11c25db14e3f8/lib/paper_listbox.dart#L61
- https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer_elements/blob/7912e0e6641155505007a89140f11c25db14e3f8/lib/paper_dropdown_menu.dart#L69

I guess the issue is because you don't use the Polymer DOM API. See also https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/local-dom. Only when you enable full shadow DOM (with full polyfills whithout native support) then you don't need to use this API.

```
makePapersElements() {
  List _items = new List();

  for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    PaperItem item = new PaperItem();
    item.text = i;

    _items.add(item);
  }

  return _items;
}
```

```
List<PaperItem> items = makePapersElements();

var element = new dom.Element.tag('div');

PaperDropdownMenu dropMenu = new PaperDropdownMenu();
PaperListbox listBox = new PaperListbox();


Polymer.dom(dropMenu).append(listBox);

// not sure this will work 
Polymer.dom(listBox).childNodes.addAll(items);

// alternatively
var listboxDom = Polymer.dom(listBox);
for(var item in items) {
  listboxDom.append(item);
}

Polymer.dom(this)appen(dropMenu);
// ro Polymer.dom(this.root)appen(dropMenu);


Polymer.dom($['example']).append(element);
```

Comment: I had tried use Polymer.dom. I get only paper-dropdown-menu element in DOM.

Comment: But you don't get any error message? Can you update your question with the code you're actually using?

Comment: For elements to be shown within `PaperDropdownMenu` it needs to have the class `class="dropdown-content"`. Adding `   listBox.classes.add("dropdown-content");` after creating the `PaperListbox` element should do the trick. See also https://github.com/bwu-dart-playground/polymer1/blob/12a4bca9c5c5b21c690af0bd4451407b64899a6e/so36689312_programmatically_create_paper_elements/web/pdm_element.dart#L36-L36 and https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu

Comment: I tried `listboxDom.classList.add('dropdown-content');` and     `listBox.classes.add("dropdown-content");`, but no effect.

Comment: In the project linked to in my previous comments it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do it wrong. Example helped. Thanks. 
https://github.com/bwu-dart-playground/polymer1/blob/12a4bca9c5c5b21c690af0bd4451407b64899a6e/so36689312_programmatically_create_paper_elements/web/pdm_element.dart#L36-L36